# EF 6 Receive data from SQL View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, backend

**UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED:**

So I managed to solve this. The reason why I wasnt able to get any data earlier was because EF was trying to access a table called "NodeView" but there is no table like that but a view hence no results.
Thats why I did this

```
 var test = _context.NodeView.FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.nodeIcons");
 var nodes = from n in test
             where n.Rootid == 1
             orderby n.Parentid, n.Lvl, n.Position ascending
             select new TreeNode()
```

I'm directly accessing the view now and create TreeNode objects based on that results afterwards

---

I have this problem with accessing data from an SQL View using Entity Framework 6 but can't find a solution for this.

**What am I doing?:**

I am currently developing a treeview using .NET Core with EF 6 and Angular 5.

This is how my backend currently looks like

**View Model**

```
public class NodeView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public int Rootid { get; set; }
    public int Parentid { get; set; }
    public int? Lvl { get; set; }
    public int? Position { get; set; }
    public string Expanded { get; set; }
    public string Collapsed { get; set; }
    public string DefIcon { get; set; }
}
```

**Node Model**

```
    public partial class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public int Rootid { get; set; }
    public int Parentid { get; set; }
    public int? Lvl { get; set; }
    public int? Position { get; set; }
}
```

**DBContext**

```
    public partial class NodeContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Node> Node { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<NodeView> NodeView { get; set; }

    public NodeContext(DbContextOptions<NodeContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Node>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("node");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("ID")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.Descr)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("DESCR")
                .HasMaxLength(256)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Lvl).HasColumnName("LVL");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("NAME")
                .HasMaxLength(256)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Parentid).HasColumnName("PARENTID");

            entity.Property(e => e.Position).HasColumnName("POSITION");

            entity.Property(e => e.Rootid).HasColumnName("ROOTID");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<NodeView>(entity => { entity.HasKey(e => e.Id); });
    }
}
```

In my controller, I am creating treenode objects of this DTO class

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string ExpandedIcon { get; set; }
    public string CollapsedIcon { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int RootId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    public TreeNode()
    {
    }


    public void AddChild(TreeNode child)
    {
        if(Children == null)
        {
            Children = new List<TreeNode>();
        }
        Children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

My frontend requires a specific data structure. Currently, I'm creating this in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public List<TreeNode> GetNodes()
    {
        var nodes = from n in _context.NodeView
                    where n.Rootid == 1
                    orderby n.Parentid, n.Lvl, n.Position ascending
                    select new TreeNode()
                    {
                        ID = n.Id,
                        Label = n.Name,
                        Data = n.Descr,
                        ExpandedIcon = n.Expanded,
                        CollapsedIcon = n.Collapsed,
                        Icon = n.DefIcon,
                        RootId = n.Rootid,
                        ParentId = n.Parentid,
                        Level = n.Lvl.Value,
                        Position = n.Position.Value
                    };

        Dictionary<int,TreeNode> parentDict = new Dictionary<int, TreeNode>();
        List<TreeNode> rootTree = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (TreeNode aNode in nodes)
        {
            if(aNode.ParentId == 0)
            {
                parentDict.Add(aNode.ID, aNode);
                rootTree.Add(aNode);
            }
            else
            {
                TreeNode fatherNode = parentDict[aNode.ParentId];
                fatherNode.AddChild(aNode);
                parentDict.Add(aNode.ID, aNode);
            }
        }
        return rootTree;
    }
```

I create a list **nodes** and add all my data from my view **NodeView**

Afterwards I'm going through that list and look for the children/parent of each node.

**ParentID == 0** is the root node. The first node of the tree. Everything else is a children node and perhaps a parent node as well. After finding a children in the else clause I'm looking for its father and add it into parentDict. At the end I'm returning the rootTree with the entire tree.

This worked properly using my **Node Model**. However it doesnt work with the *NodeView Model**

**Error message: Invalid objectname: NodeView**

I dont really know what causes this problem but I believe its either somewhere in the DBContext where I created a second modelbuilder function for **NodeView** right at the bottom or I'm doing something wrong while selecting the view in my LINQ statement which returns zero objects hence I cant iterate in the the foreach loop.

**=> Program stops at the start of the foreach loop**

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, and then accept it when you can. Otherwise, this question will remain in a perpetual "Unanswered" state.

Comment: Ok, will do it :)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this. The reason why I wasnt able to get any data earlier was because EF was trying to access a table called "NodeView" but there is no table like that but a view hence no results. Thats why I did this

```
 var test = _context.NodeView.FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.nodeIcons");
 var nodes = from n in test
             where n.Rootid == 1
             orderby n.Parentid, n.Lvl, n.Position ascending
             select new TreeNode()
```

I'm directly accessing the view now and create TreeNode objects based on that results afterwards